# Refresh record page from popup

Tags: visualforce, javascript, popup-window

I have a list button which opens a popup. I am performing some operation there and when I click on 'Close' button(command button in my VF page). Then it will close the popup and refresh the detail page. It is working as expected when pop up is open from related list section but it is not working if I click from the iframe pop up from related list on the top record page.
the javascript I am using for the function to close is

```
window.opener.location.href = "/{!recordId}";                
window.close();
```

it is working if popup opened from here
[image]

it is not working if popup opened from here
[image]

Comment: In the second screen are you opening the popup from inside an iframe?

Comment: yes @Ritesh, I am opening popup from inside an iframe which gets hidden after popup opens. and  Javascript is unable to find popup's opener or parent.